# Ubuntu 14.04 Wine program files association

Tags: wine, pdf, file-association

this question has been asked in a general way before, but this is my first week with Ubuntu and I can't understand all the instructions here: [How to associate a file with a program installed in wine](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6765/how-to-associate-a-file-with-a-program-installed-in-wine) Danne's answer was: 'Right click, Open with other application. If your application is not available in the list, use custom command and put wine ~/.wine/drive_c/Program\ Files/Yourapp/Yourapp.exe in the box.' What is 'custom command'?

I also saw the instructions at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Wine#Creating_file_associations But the other way looks easier..

In particular I want to open pdf files with Sumatra PDF. I have Ubuntu 14.04.

Thanks for your help,

Andrew

Answer (score 0):

Lets create an association file!

Open up your Terminal and execute command:

> gedit ~/.local/share/applications/ViewInSumatra.desktop

You will get the text editor. There, paste something like below:

> [Desktop Entry]
>   Name=Sumatra
>   Exec=wine `/home/$USER/.wine/c_drive/Program\ Files/Sumatra/sumatrapdf.exe` %F
>   Icon=evince
>   Type=Application
>   Categories=Viewer 
>   StartupNotify=false
>   Terminal=false
>   MimeType=application/pdf

**NOTE:** You must replace `/home/$USER/.wine/c_drive/Program Files/Sumatra/sumatrapdf.exe` with the real path of Sumatra PDF Reader.

Once done save the text file.

Now, right click a PDF file > choose `Open With` > CLick `View All Applications`
From the application list, choose `Sumatra`:

[image]

Now all the PDF files should be opened with Sumatra

### With that said, I must say that `Sumatra PDF` is no match for [KDE's Okular](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/okular/)

Comment: Thanks a lot, Naveen. Before I get started on that, does Okular work OK with the Unity Desktop? I just discovered that I can change to the KDE Desktop without a new installation. Is that the way to go? Does Okular work better with the KDE Desktop? Andrew

Comment: I just tried Okular with Unity. It's quite a bit slower than Sumatra, which is itself a lot slower than Adobe or Foxit with Windows 7. This is my one problem now, and I use long old books a lot. I can't even scroll with Okular without waiting several seconds for each page to load.

Comment: Foxit exists for Linux: http://www.foxitsoftware.com/downloads/thanks.php?product=Foxit-Reader&platform=Desktop-Linux

Comment: Adobe Reader Exists for Linux: https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/acroread/

Comment: And there are plenty of other open source PDF readers for Linux: http://alternativeto.net/software/adobe-reader/?license=free&platform=linux

Comment: Hi Naveen, I tried those instructions. Sumatra showed up on the list of programs, but it still opens in Document Viewer. If I right click on a pdf, Sumatra shows up now in the list, but it doesn't open.

Comment: I saw that Adobe link, but it doesn't give Ubuntu 14.04, so am not sure if it would work. I read this thread: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1978238 - the only thing that seemed to work was to used Wine. Andrew

Comment: Actually, that ViewInSumatra.desktop file stopped Sumatra opening. I had to delete it to get it working again. Andrew