# Is there a download manager for all videos?

Tags: download-manager

I am new to using Linux and I am still trying to figure out how to do things.

Is there some programs that I can install that will allow me to download videos not just in YouTube but to all webpages as the application IDM does in Windows?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use IDM on Mozilla Firefox Quantum](https://askubuntu.com/questions/987204/how-to-use-idm-on-mozilla-firefox-quantum)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, try [Xtream download manager](https://sourceforge.net/projects/xdman/) and install the browser plugin, it will automatically detect any downloadable video from the webpage.

[image]

Comment: it worked!!! thank you so much!!