# iDM internet ownload manager

Tags: firefox, browser, idm

IDM installed on ubuntu 22.04
I can not fix Mozilla Firefox as browser, nor use the "advanced browser integration"

Any suggestion
ThanksDM

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How I can install "Internet Download Manager" on Ubuntu 14.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/554062/how-i-can-install-internet-download-manager-on-ubuntu-14-04)

Comment: While this is an old question for an older release of Ubuntu, it may be helpful. I don't know that iDM will work on Ubuntu with a Firefox contained in a snap though.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use IDM on Mozilla Firefox Quantum](https://askubuntu.com/questions/987204/how-to-use-idm-on-mozilla-firefox-quantum)

Comment: Hello Popey, Thank you for your kind advice. I know that web. It works with Flashgot. But Flashgot does not work any more with FireFox

Comment: Dear Karel. I tried the adds-on. But there seems no integration with FireFox.

Comment: My Firefox problem is that I have to choose, in IMD, a browser. No browser is accepted as such. I receive the remark : I have to use the "Advanced Browser Integration". Trying it I receive the remark that the "Base Filtering Engine" is missing

Comment: I think you should try the [uget answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/997215/).